# Printing bootstrap modal to PDF

Tags: javascript, c#, itext, jspdf, html2canvas

I have some modals that I would like to print to PDF.  I've managed to get *something* to print, but it's just not quite right.

Here's a break down of what I'm currently doing:

- The modal pops up, and the user interacts with it. The user clicks 'Accept'
- I clone the modal, I append the clone to the document below the fold.
- I turn it into a canvas via html2canvas and create an image of the
  canvas with `.toDataURL`
- I add the image to `jsPDF` object with `addImage`
- I remove the cloned modal from the document.

The issue I'm having is that the image is cropped, but only just barely.  The very bottom of the accept button is missing.

I read somewhere that setting the width and height of the clone to 3000 could help with that, but no changes.  I tried playing with the addImage parameters, but nothing.

I could also do this server side, but my quick playing around with iTextSharp didn't pan out either.  It didn't show values of radio buttons or textboxes, which are very much needed.

I've been messing with this for 2 days, but I'm at a loss.

Cloning code:

```
hiddenClone: (element) => {
   const clone = element.cloneNode(true);

   clone.classList.remove('modal-content');

   const style = clone.style;
   style.position = 'relative';
   style.top = window.innerHeight + 'px';
   style.left = 0;
   style.width = '3000px';
   style.height = '3000px';
   style.background = '#fff';

   document.body.appendChild(clone);
   return clone;
}
```

pdf code:

```
const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
const clone = utils.hiddenClone(form);

html2canvas(clone).then((canvas) => {
  const img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 1.0)
  pdf.deletePage(1);
  pdf.addPage("p");
  pdf.addImage(img, 'PNG', 10, 0, 150, 180);
  const blob = pdf.output('blob');
    $.ajax({
       url: `/profile/People/SignedDocument/${id}`,
       type: "POST",
       data: blob,
       contentType: "application/pdf; charset=utf-8",
       processData: false
    });
});
```

Comment: I see that you tried to generate PDF server-side with iTextSharp. That's the old version of iText .NET. Could you try again, with iText 7 (7.1.6 was released a few days ago) + the pdfHTML add-on? It has much improved HTML and CSS support.

Comment: The PDF that is generated looks great using iText, however the radio button that is selected on the screen is NOT selected on the generated PDF.  I've spent about 5 minutes on this and will continue to investigate how to use this tool.
Server side code: `HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, new FileStream(sMdocFile, FileMode.Create));`

Comment: I see that if I add a 'checked' attribute to the radio that is selected, the iText will select it.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse If you want to make an answer I'll accept it.
Just to add a few things I did to make the PDF come out the way I needed it to:
I had to check all radios: 
`document.querySelectorAll('#custom-form-container input[type="radio"]:checked').forEach((element) => {
                element.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
            });`

I had to insert the value to text boxes:
`document.querySelectorAll('#custom-form-container input[type="text"]').forEach((element) => {
                element.setAttribute('value', element.value);
            });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you tried to generate PDF server-side with iTextSharp. That's the old version of iText .NET. Please try again, with iText 7 (7.1.6 was released a few days ago) + the pdfHTML add-on. It has much improved HTML and CSS support.

Your server-side code can essentially be as short as:

```
HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, new FileStream(sMdocFile, FileMode.Create));
```

When you add a 'checked' attribute to the radio that is selected, then iText will select it.

Use something like this, as you already wrote yourself in your comment:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#custom-form-container input[type="radio"]:checked').forEach((element) => {
    element.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Comment: May have run into a snag using iText; pricing.  It's not free for what we need it seems, and I'm not sure if the boss will be into it.

Comment: Well yeah you are a programmer and I suppose you like to be paid at the end of the month, well it's the same thing with the people who work at iText Software. Also, if nobody pays developers who work on Open Source, then you get things like the Heartbleed bug in OpenSSL, which went undetected for more than two years, simply because a handful of overworked volunteers missed the bug. Trust me, convincing your boss isn't a problem at all.

Comment: Convincing my boss IS the problem.  I don't mind sharing my stuff; I'm down for AGPL, or having the company pay for it.  I don't need the holier-then-thou attitude.

Comment: Ouch, if I were your boss and I read on a public forum that I am the problem, then that would hurt my feelings. But I trust that you know your boss better than I do, and I will believe you when you write that the boss is the problem. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯